# cannot update ftp credentials even when group owner has write access

Tags: updates

Why doesn't update work for wp?

_www has write permission to everything as you can see.[image]

But it always asks for ftp credentials. Only way is to have wp dir owned by _www. Why?

Comment: Are the permissions recursive to sub folders also?

Comment: @bravokeyl yep, I noticed wordpress always wants _www:_www otherwise it refuses to update.